# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Can't find a solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs

The code compiles successfully but on localhost it drops me an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
    
    const Module = (props) => {
        const courses = props.courses;
        console.log(props.courses);
        let Course = courses.map(item=><li>{item}</li>)
        
        return(
            <ul>{Course}</ul>
        )
    }
    
    export default Module;
```

Comment: And what do *you* think props.courses is? Did you do any debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `props.courses` is undefined at some point; probably before data is asynchronously loaded.

You have a few options!

**Option 1:** Default `courses` to an empty array. This will solve the error but maybe confusing to users because the loading state is unclear

```
const Module = (props) => {
  const courses = props.courses || [];
  console.log(props.courses);
  let Course = courses.map(item=><li>{item}</li>)
  return(
    <ul>{Course}</ul>
  )
}
```

**Option 2:** Only map over the data when it exists; otherwise display a loading indicator. This might be better for user experience.

```
const Module = (props) => {
  const courses = props.courses;

  if (!courses) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  let Course = courses.map(item=><li>{item}</li>)
  return(
    <ul>{Course}</ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `props` contains data:

```
import React from 'react';

const Module = (props) => {
    const { courses } = props;
    const Course = courses && courses.length > 0 ? courses.map(item=><li>{item}</li>) : null;
    return Course ? (<ul>{Course}</ul>) : null;
}

export default Module;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **destructuring**, as well as **default parameters** to prevent the above error, and reduce code.

```
const Module = ({courses = []}) => {
    console.log(courses);
    return <ul>
        {courses.map(item=><li>{item}</li>)}
    </ul>;
};
```